# Multiple controllers in routing

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

I may have a lame question, but I am struggling a bit with routing of multiple controllers in one Url. So my question is how to work with a url like this:

```
GET http://foo.com/API/Devices/2/Parameters/2
```

where eventually `device` and `parameters` are all controllers and numbers are Ids. I have controllers for each of them but how do process them, route them to proper controller?

Any direction to look at?

**UPDATE:**
Just for clarification the solution which I ended up using and follows the answer below.

Routing snippet:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DeviceCommandsControllerHttpRoute", 
            routeTemplate: "api/devices/{deviceId}/commands/{id}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "devicecommands", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Controller snippet:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public DeviceCommand GetById(int id, int deviceId)
    { ... }
```

and finally the URL:

```
GET http://localhost:49479/api/Devices/2/Commands/1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am working with a smilar need right now and I have the following route structure:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(HttpRouteCollection routes) {

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "UserRolesHttpRoute",
        "api/users/{key}/roles",
        new { controller = "UserRoles" });

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "AffiliateShipmentsHttpRoute",
        "api/affiliates/{key}/shipments",
        new { controller = "AffiliateShipments" });

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "ShipmentStatesHttpRoute",
        "api/shipments/{key}/shipmentstates",
        new { controller = "ShipmentStates" });

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "AffiliateShipmentShipmentStatesHttpRoute",
        "api/affiliates/{key}/shipments/{shipmentKey}/shipmentstates",
        new { controller = "AffiliateShipmentShipmentStates" });

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "DefaultHttpRoute",
        "api/{controller}/{key}",
        new { key = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

I think you can sort of figure out how you can implement yours based on this.